# Creating a wire-frame 3D cube

Tags: wpf, xaml, 3d

I have this code which draws a cube in WPF Viewport3D:

```
        <Viewport3D Name="viewport3D1">
            <Viewport3D.Camera>
                <PerspectiveCamera x:Name="camMain" Position="6 5 4" LookDirection="-6 -5 -4">
                </PerspectiveCamera>
            </Viewport3D.Camera>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <DirectionalLight x:Name="dirLightMain" Direction="-1,-1,-1">
                    </DirectionalLight>
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <GeometryModel3D>
                        <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                            <MeshGeometry3D x:Name="meshMain"
                                Positions="0 0 0  1 0 0  0 1 0  1 1 0  0 0 1  1 0 1  0 1 1  1 1 1"
                                TriangleIndices="2 3 1  2 1 0  7 1 3  7 5 1  6 5 7  6 4 5  6 2 0  2 0 4  2 7 3  2 6 7  0 1 5  0 5 4">
                            </MeshGeometry3D>
                        </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                        <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                            <DiffuseMaterial x:Name="matDiffuseMain">
                                <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                                </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                            </DiffuseMaterial>
                        </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                    </GeometryModel3D>
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
        </Viewport3D>
```

This gives the following result:

[image]

How to make render as a wire frame?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at the `LinesVisual3D` class in the (free) Helix 3D Toolkit (https://github.com/helix-toolkit). This is a version of the 'screen space lines' that allow you to draw wireframes like your example.

I highly recommend the [Helix 3D Toolkit](https://github.com/helix-toolkit) if you are doing any WPF 3D work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

```
                <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                    <DiffuseMaterial x:Name="matDiffuseMain">
                        <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" Opacity="0.5" />
                        </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                    </DiffuseMaterial>
                </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                <GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>
                    <DiffuseMaterial x:Name="matDiffuseMain2">
                        <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" Opacity="0.5" />
                        </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                    </DiffuseMaterial>
                </GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not really what I'm looking for. Is there a way to get the same effect as in the picture?

Comment: I think that only if you build the lines as connected narrow tubes or boxes. you must keep in mind that in 3d world a 2d line has no apearance. unless it is possible to draw a simple line in 3dViewport - is it possible? check this out too:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b0c79d04-37af-489f-8601-ee9c76dd12cf/